# How to add a margin underneath the NavBar

Tags: html, css

I want to have it as if that under the navigation bar its white space for me to add other stuff. Essentially how do I add a cut-off point for how much the gray background extends to? Right now it's filling up the entire window. I want it to go a few pixels underneath all navbar. I have included a picture for reference.

```
    </head>
        <body>
                <header>
                    <img class="logo" src="img/logo.svg" alt="logo">
                    <nav>
                            <ul class="nav__links">
                                    <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                            </ul>
                    </nav>
                </header>
        <body>
</html>
```

CSS as follows
[image]
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@500&display=swap');

```
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #24252A;

}

li, a{
  font-family: "Montserrat",sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #edf0f1;
  text-decoration: none;
}


header{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 30px 10%;

}

.logo{
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-right: auto;
  position: absolute;
    width: 320px;
    height: 100px;
    left: -10px;
}

nav{
  order: 1;
}

.nav__links{
  list-style: none;
}

.nav__links li{
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0px 20px;
}

.nav__links li a{
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s
}

.nav__links li a:hover{
  color: #17E5EC
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Add either `display:block;` and `height:50px;` to  `.nav__links li a{....}`. This will allow you to add an height for your element, since `a` is a inline element it won't consider `height` property so we have to make either `block` or `inline-block` so that it can accept the height property.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li,
a {
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #edf0f1;
  text-decoration: none;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 30px 10%;
  background-color: #24252A;
}

.logo {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-right: auto;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  left: -10px;
}

img {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}

nav {
  order: 1;
}

.nav__links {
  list-style: none;
}

.nav__links li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0px 20px;
}

.nav__links li a {
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  display: block;
  height: 50px;
  width: 80px;
}

.nav__links li a:hover {
  color: #17E5EC
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <img class="logo" src="http://placekitten.com/301/301" alt="logo">
    <nav>
      <ul class="nav__links">
        <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

  </header>

  <body>
```

Comment: Ok, can you brief what is you need referring the answer above? reading your question I thought you need space below the tags.

Comment: Do you see how the background (dark grey) is extending to the whole of the window of the page? I want that color to extend full width of the nav bar but the height should be just enough to cover the logo and the "project" "about" items. Does that make sense? i am sorry if i am explaining it poorly

Comment: so you need the dark gray should fill only for the header not for the entire body? just for log and nav bar? below nav bar should be different color? something like this ? https://jsfiddle.net/Manju06/x36pr1jL/21/

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify margin size and position for the navbar,

for example:-

```
nav{
     margin-top: 25px
   }
```

also check where you specified the background color.

Comment: li, a{
  font-family: "Montserrat",sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #edf0f1;
  text-decoration: none;

}
this is where the background color was specified. can you please elaborate